# Is storing an object reference in a controls Tag property OK

Tags: c#, winforms, object

I'm creating a group of form controls for each object in a list, is it OK to store a reference to the object in the controls Tag property?

I'm doing this so I can have a generic Click event on the controls, so when they are clicked I can update a field in the object that they represent.

So the click handler will look something like this.

```
private void Item_Clicked(object sender, system.EventArgs e)
{
     if(sender.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Label))
     {
          System.Windows.Forms.Label label = (System.Windows.Forms.Label)sender;
          MyObject myObject = label.Tag;
          myObject.Value = true;
     }
}
```

Is this an acceptable thing to do in this situation, or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is legal to do and is one of the patterns the `Tag` property was designed for.

The biggest danger here is that another peice of code attempts to use the same `Tag` property for their own feature.  This would create a race for the `Tag` property and lead to runtime bugs.  A safer approach would be to create a private map between a `Label` and `MyObject` using a `Dictionary` instance.

```
private Dictionary<Label,MyObject> _map = new Dictionary<Label,MyObject>();
...
private void Item_Clicked(object sender, system.EventArgs e) 
{ 
     if(sender.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Label)) 
     { 
          System.Windows.Forms.Label label = (System.Windows.Forms.Label)sender;
          MyObject myObject = _map[label];
          myObject.Value = true; 
     } 
}
```

This approach has the extra overhead of a `Dictionary` but produces more reliable code (IMHO).

Comment: That approach would work if I was only using Labels.  My example was a shortened version of what I'm doing.  In reality I have a few if statements to determine what type of control was clicked. In my case should I create a Dictionary like this  Dictionary<Control,MyObject>?

Comment: @Tester101 yes if you need to map Controls (not just Labels as in your example) to MyObject then that would work

Comment: I think if two or more threads modify one dictionary you have the same problem as with the Tag property.. Only reading is still a viable solution, but then you could also use the Property Tag, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's acceptable if it works for you.  I've stored things in the tag properly like this before, and it works fine.  Things to consider: the size of the object you're storing and the lifecyle of the object (could it be disposed of or destroyed between accesses).

Another approach, that I have used, is to store a "hint" that would help you retreive or recreate the object.  For example, if it's a database object, store the Id property (maybe an integer or Guid) which is much [potentially] much smaller than the object itself.