# Tag property in 64 bit misused for storing object references

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm converting 32-bit code to 64-bit and there's a lot of use of the `.Tag` property.
Many of those are just for storing integer values, and then assignments like `MyInteger := Component.Tag`, although formally wrong (can lead to range check error), will keep working. Since there are no compiler hints/warnings for these assignments, I decided to leave them. It's our own code that put integers into the tags on the first place...

But in other places pointers to objects were placed in the `.Tag` propery, e.g. like this:

```
procedure IntervalWeergaveSubMenuToevoegen( AParentMenu : TMenuItem; ACaption : String; AInterval : TcxPivotGridGroupInterval; AField : TcxDBPivotGridField );
var lSubMenuItem : TMenuItem;
begin
  lSubMenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  lSubMenuItem.Caption := ACaption;
  lSubMenuItem.ImageIndex := Integer(AInterval);  // (Mis-)use ImageIndex property to store interval
  lSubMenuItem.Tag := Integer(AField);            // (Mis-)use Tag property to store reference to field  THIS ONE!
  lSubMenuItem.GroupIndex := 99;               
  lSubMenuItem.RadioItem := True;
  lSubMenuItem.Checked := (AField.GroupInterval=AInterval);
  lSubMenuItem.OnClick := PopupSubMenuWeergaveClick;
  AParentMenu.Add(lSubMenuItem);
end;
```

Then `PopupSubMenuWeergaveClick`, which receives a `TMenuItem` as its `Sender`, casts the `.Tag` back to a `TcxDBPivotGridField`:

```
procedure TDialoogDynRapport.PopupSubMenuWeergaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  ExcelPivotGrid.BeginUpdate;
  try                                  // TcxDBPivotGridField reference was put in MenuItem.Tag
    TcxDBPivotGridField(TMenuItem(Sender).Tag).GroupInterval := TcxPivotGridGroupInterval( TMenuItem(Sender).ImageIndex );
  finally
    ExcelPivotGrid.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Not very nice, I know.

I see two ways out:

- The routine `IntervalWeergaveSubMenuToevoegen` is contained in a `TDialoogDynRapport` method, so I could give `TDialoogDynRapport` an extra private structure to store the association between the `TMenuItem` and `TcxDBPivotGridField`. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927067/is-storing-an-object-reference-in-a-controls-tag-property-ok)
- Just change the `Integer(AField)` assignment to another cast. After all `.Tag` is now 8 bytes, as is the address of the `TcxDBPivotGridField`

What is recommended?
Delphi 11.3, no multithreading, should keep working in Win32 as well.

Comment: `Tag` properties are commonly used to store pointers. That's why almost all of them are native-sized integers. So `X.Tag := NativeInt(SomeObj)` is not only correct, but even idiomatic. But, of course, `X.Tag := Integer(SomeObj)` is a nasty bug in any 64-bit application. (But see RSP-39424!)

Comment: (Well, idiomatic but slightly "lazy". Of course you don't get any compile-time type checks or anything. So one might argue that it in many cases is better to define an additional field of the specific (class) type.)

Comment: Just in case you will ever compile with an older Delphi version and for 32 bits again, don't typecast to NativeInt, but to IntPtr instead. NativeInt is not always declared correctly, while IntPtr should always be the same size as Pointer.

Comment: If you ask me `Tag` properties should be **banned**. Why? First reason is because they are wasting a bit of memory for every created component since [Tag](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Tag) property is defined as part of TComponent class itself. Second reason is that by using `Tag` properties you are hurting code readability. As you noted yourself people tend to store all sort of things in `Tag` property.

Comment: Do you know that in FireMonkey each FMX object actually has four `Tag` properties? Yes In FMX you have ordinary [Tag](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Tag) property, [TagFloat](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.TagFloat) property, [TagString](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.TagString) and finally [TagObject](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.TagObject). Care to calculate how much memory you are wasting with these `Tag` properties?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need the "tag" property at all.

There's a much nicer way to map a tMenuitem to one or more objects.  You can simply use a tDictionary (= fast lookup engine) that uses a tMenuitem as the key.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
Uses system.generics.collections, ..... ;

var fieldlookup: tDictionary <tMenuitem, TcxDBPivotGridField>;
    intervalLookup: tDictionary <tMenuitem, TcxPivotGridGroupInterval>;

Procedure initialization;
begin
 fieldlookup:=tDictionary <tMenuitem, TcxDBPivotGridField>.Create;
 intervallookup:=tDictionary <tMenuitem, TcxPivotGridGroupInterval>.Create;
end;

Procedure IntervalWeergaveSubMenuToevoegen( 
      AParentMenu : TMenuItem; 
      ACaption : String; 
      AInterval : TcxPivotGridGroupInterval; 
      AField : TcxDBPivotGridField);
var lSubMenuItem : TMenuItem;
begin
     lSubMenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
     fieldlookup.add(lSubMenuItem, AField);
     intervallookup.add(lSubMenuItem, AInterval);         
     lSubMenuItem.Caption := ACaption; 
     lSubMenuItem.GroupIndex := 99;               
     lSubMenuItem.RadioItem := True;
     lSubMenuItem.Checked := (AField.GroupInterval=AInterval);
     lSubMenuItem.OnClick := PopupSubMenuWeergaveClick;
     AParentMenu.Add(lSubMenuItem);              
end;




procedure TDialoogDynRapport.PopupSubMenuWeergaveClick(
          Sender: TObject);
Var Field:TcxDBPivotGridField; Interval:TcxPivotGridGroupInterval;
begin
  if (fieldlookup.TryGetValue(sender as tmenuitem, Field) and 
  intervallookup.Trygetvalue(sender as tmenuitem, Interval)) then
  begin
   {Field and interval are now known. Insert rest of event handler code here}
  end;
end;
```